# how android install v4l2loopback driver?

Tags: android, driver, v4l2loopback

today,i compile android driver —— v4l2loopback on ubuntu 12.04,and then, i push this v4l2loopback.ko to android through adb,and then run this command: **insmod v4l2loopback**,and then through command **dmesg**,i get this tips:

```
<7>[110639.274146] (0)[31252:insmod][exec] /system/bin/insmod(3)
<4>[110639.277463] (0)[31252:insmod]Kernel Taint Module!!
<4>[110639.277657] (0)[31252:insmod]v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol video_ioctl2 (err 0)
<4>[110639.277712] (0)[31252:insmod]v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol kmem_cache_alloc_trace (err 0)
<4>[110639.277740] (0)[31252:insmod]v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol video_devdata (err 0)
<4>[110639.277769] (0)[31252:insmod]v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol v4l2_ctrl_new_custom (err 0)
<4>[110639.277791] (0)[31252:insmod]v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol video_unregister_device (err 0)
<4>[110639.277814] (0)[31252:insmod]v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol video_device_alloc (err 0)
<4>[110639.277839] (0)[31252:insmod]v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol v4l2_device_register (err 0)
<4>[110639.277868] (0)[31252:insmod]v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol __video_register_device (err 0)
<4>[110639.277885] (0)[31252:insmod]v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol v4l2_ctrl_handler_init (err 0)
<4>[110639.277902] (0)[31252:insmod]v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol v4l2_ctrl_handler_free (err 0)
<4>[110639.277920] (0)[31252:insmod]v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol v4l2_device_unregister (err 0)
<4>[110639.277938] (0)[31252:insmod]v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol video_device_release (err 0)
```

so i want to know:
this android is my real android phone,what should i need to do ?
if i install this driver success,will my camera auto invoke this driver?